# How to return everything before X characters?

Tags: java, string

Say user enters a string, like `"My name is Oz, the great and powerful"`.  I have cut off `"My name is"` using substring, but I want to cut off `", the great and powerful"` and keep only `Oz`.

Is there any method of doing this ?

Keeping in mind that the user entered String is unknown to us.

Comment: "the user entered String is unknown to us" But is the format known to us? Does always start with "My name is ", followed by the thing you want, followed by a comma? And what is "X" (in the title)?

Comment: Do you always want to get `Oz` or something ? whats the `constant` with the user entered strings?

Comment: I always want to get the name of the user; and yes, it always starts with " my name is " . Followed by a comma or space Andy Turner and 3kings

Comment: Sooooo whatever the beginning of the name should start at `index = 11` then you want to subString to `substring(11, string.indexOf(","));`

Comment: Will the result be Oz 3kings ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: Try it out :P it should be for that specific String

Comment: Is there any other way ?

Comment: I mean that way is pretty easy... Can't think of another way just to do it

Comment: 3kings if there is a space instead of a comma ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), you have to identify the pattern that it will match, and this is easy in your case as the string before the name is fixed **"My name is"** and there are a comma after the name, so the pattern will be `(My name is )(.*)(,)(.*)` and that makes the output generated using the following code:

```
// String to be scanned to find the pattern.
String line = "My name is Oz, the great and powerful";
String pattern = "(My name is )(.*)(,)(.*)";

// Create a Pattern object
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

// Now create matcher object.
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find( )) {
   String name = m.group(2);
}
```

and if there is no comma the pattern has to be:

```
String pattern = "(My name is )([A-Z]*[a-z]*)(\\s)(.*)";
```

---

You can have a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm), it's a great tutorial for it.